# vlc-android-sdk - cannot view RTSP live video

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

I've been working on an Android application that shows live streaming video via RTSP.
Assuming I have a well-functioning RTSP server that passes h264 packets, and to view the stream we should connect to [rtsp://1.2.3.4:5555/stream](http://rtsp://1.2.3.4:5555/stream)

So I tried to use the native MediaPlayer\VideoView, but no luck (the video was stuck after 2-3 seconds of playback, so I loaded mrmaffen's vlc-android-sdk (can be found [here](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk)) and used the following code:

```
            ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
            options.add("--no-drop-late-frames");
            options.add("--no-skip-frames");
            options.add("-vvv");
            videoVlc = new LibVLC(options);

            newVideoMediaPlayer = new org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer(videoVlc);
            final IVLCVout vOut = newVideoMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
            vOut.addCallback(this);
            vOut.setVideoView(videoView); //videoView is a pre-defined view which is part of the layout
            vOut.attachViews();
            newVideoMediaPlayer.setEventListener(this);

            Media videoMedia = new Media (videoVlc, Uri.parse(mVideoPath));
            newVideoMediaPlayer.setMedia(videoMedia);
            newVideoMediaPlayer.play();
```

The problem is that I see a blank screen.

Keep in mind that when I put a RTSP link with audio stream only, it works fine.

Is someone familliar with this sdk and have an idea about this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you solved this problem using [vlc-android-sdk](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk)?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this option:

```
--rtsp-tcp
```

Comment: Thanks, it work's! Even VLC for Android from Google Play can't play some streams (as it doesn't have this option). In code:   options.add("--rtsp-tcp"); new LibVLC(context, options);

Answer (score 1):

I play rtsp streaming with following code

```
try {
        Uri rtspUri=Uri.parse("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov");


        final MediaWrapper mw = new MediaWrapper(rtspUri);
        mw.removeFlags(MediaWrapper.MEDIA_FORCE_AUDIO);
        mw.addFlags(MediaWrapper.MEDIA_VIDEO);

        MediaWrapperListPlayer.getInstance().getMediaList().add(mw);

        VLCInstance.getMainMediaPlayer().setEventListener(this);
    VLCInstance.get().setOnHardwareAccelerationError(this);


    final IVLCVout vlcVout = VLCInstance.getMainMediaPlayer().getVLCVout();
    vlcVout.addCallback(this);
    vlcVout.setVideoView(mSurfaceView);
    vlcVout.attachViews();
    final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final String aout = VLCOptions.getAout(pref);
    VLCInstance.getMainMediaPlayer().setAudioOutput(aout);
    MediaWrapperListPlayer.getInstance().playIndex(this, 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
```

When you get playing event, you need enable video track.

```
private void onPlaying() {
    stopLoadingAnimation();
    VLCInstance.getMainMediaPlayer().setVideoTrackEnabled(true);
}
```

This may be helpful for you